# How to use OpenGLES2 with PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, graphics, opengl-es, raspberry-pi, pyopengl

how can I call GLES2 from PyOpenGL? It's in experimental state but I don't know how to import it. Does someone know this I only know that I can import it with`from OpenGL import GL`. Or does I only can import OpenGL?  Then how to call GLES2?

Answer (score 1):

I've used it like this:

```
from OpenGL.GLES2 import *
```